Enable/Disable Power of Board with ESP32-S3
I am using TPS63001 Buck-Boost Coverter with a 3.7 Li-Ion Recharable battery. I want to Control Power of the board with ESP32-S3-Mini. Enable pin of the TPS63001 is connected to MCU and its also pulled high with risistor divider circuit. (EN low-0.4V, EN High-1.2V) as per datasheet. My issue is if I turn off the TPS63001 By pulling EN pin down with MCU then how system will turn on again? Because if TPS63001 is pulled down then it will also power off ESP32 with rest of the circuit so how System will turn on again if EN pin is Low? I cant pull EN pin high because ESP32 will also shut down. Will connecting power again to the board make the EN pin high again?
Schematic is attached


What is your use case? Is the output of the converter used for any other purpose or only for powering ESP? Can you use any other power converter for ESP (directly from the source)?

its used to power all the components of the PCB. Actually i want to turn off whole system by controlling EN of this converter. So thats why i asked about it

Okay, you can turn off everything except the control circuitry (here, the MCU). else you won't be able to turn it on again. you may use the available power or another rechargeable battery just for the MCU. Then only you could take control of the on/off process.
